# Python Regex Extract Date to New Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I'm scraping a website using Python and I'm having troubles with extracting the dates and creating a new Date dataframe with Regex.

**The code below is using BeautifulSoup to scrape event data and the event links:**

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.techmeme.com/events').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

event = []
links = []

# ---Event Data---
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    event.append(a.text)

df_event = pd.DataFrame(event)
df_event.columns = ['Event']
df_event = df_event.iloc[1:]

# ---Links---
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
    if a.text: 
        links.append(a['href'])
df_link = pd.DataFrame(links)
df_link.columns = ['Links']

# ---Combines dfs---
df = pd.concat([df_event.reset_index(drop=True),df_link.reset_index(drop=True)],sort=False, axis=1)
```

At the beginning of the each event data row, the date is present. Example: (May 26-29Augmented World ExpoSan...). The date follows the following format and I have included my Regex(which I believe is correct).

```
Different Date Formats:
May 27: [A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}
May 26-29:  [A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}
May 28-Jun 2: [A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}

Combined
[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}
```

When I try to create a new column and extract the dates using Regex, I just receive an empty `df['Date']` column.

```
df['Date'] = df['Event'].str.extract(r[A-Z][a-z]*(\ )[0-9]{1,2}')
df.head()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is the information provided in this question enough for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62009216/12239523. I think it is similar but i may be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
date_reg = r'([A-Z][a-z]* [0-9]{1,2}(?:-(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )?[0-9]{1,2})?)'
df['Date'] = df['Event'].str.extract(date_reg, expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oFdYBt/2). If you want to match as whole words and numbers, you may use `(?<![A-Za-z])([A-Z][a-z]* [0-9]{1,2}(?:-(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )?[0-9]{1,2})?)(?!\d)`.

**Details**

- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase letter and then 0 or more lowercase letters
- - a space (replace with `\s` to match any whitespace)
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `(?:-(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )?[0-9]{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `-` - hyphen
  - `(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )?` - an optional sequence of

    - `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase letter and then 0 or more lowercase letters
    - - a space (replace with `\s` to match any whitespace)
  - `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits

The `(?<![A-Za-z])` construct is a lookbehind that fails the match if there is a letter immediately before the current location and `(?!\d)` fails the match if there is a digit immediately after.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! This makes a lot of sense now. That site looks like a great learning tool. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was able to create the new date column, however, the original date is still present in the event column. How would I go about deleting that? I was assuming  extract did that.

Comment: @LeslieTate If you want to remove the dates from the *Event* column, you need to use `str.replace` on it, use `df['Event'] = df['Event'].str.replace(date_reg, '')`. `str.extract` only finds a match, it does not remove anything.

Comment: Ahh, that's great to know. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

This script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.techmeme.com/events'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = []
for row in soup.select('.rhov a'):
    date, event, place = map(lambda x: x.get_text(strip=True), row.find_all('div', recursive=False))
    data.append({'Date': date, 'Event': event, 'Place': place, 'Link': 'https://www.techmeme.com' + row['href']})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

will create this dataframe:

```
          Date                                           Event          Place                                               Link
0    May 26-29                NOW VIRTUAL:Augmented World Expo    Santa Clara      https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/www.awexr.com/
1       May 27                               Earnings: HPQ,BOX                 https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/finance.yahoo.c...
2       May 28                              Earnings: CRM, VMW                 https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/finance.yahoo.c...
3    May 28-29         CANCELED:WeAreDevelopers World Congress         Berlin  https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/www.wearedevelo...
4        Jun 2                                    Earnings: ZM                 https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/finance.yahoo.c...
..         ...                                             ...            ...                                                ...
140   Dec 7-10                         NEW DATE:GOTO Amsterdam      Amsterdam         https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/gotoams.nl/
141   Dec 8-10                 Microsoft Azure + AI Conference      Las Vegas  https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/azureaiconf.com...
142   Dec 9-10           NEW DATE:Paris Blockchain Week Summit          Paris  https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/www.pbwsummit.com/
143  Dec 13-16                          NEW DATE:KNOW Identity      Las Vegas  https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/www.knowidentit...
144  Dec 15-16  NEW DATE, NEW LOCATION:Fortune Brainstorm Tech  San Francisco  https://www.techmeme.com/gotos/fortuneconferen...

[145 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: This is a much easier solution! I guess it shows how this can be done in much less lines of code. I don't see the links included in the df.

Comment: @LeslieTate I updated my answer to include Link as well.